# Changing permission on GeoNode 2.8

Tags: geonode

I'm working on `GeoNode 2.8` and I would like to change the authorization on layers. For example, actually people who are logged can see all the maps and layers but if they are not they can't see it. I would like to change it in the code to be able to let everyone see layers etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my way, I just had to add the `{% if is.user_authentificated %}` in the layer_detail.html file, in the line I needed.